# How to dynamically update MySQL offset in php within android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Is there a way to dynamically assign `:val1` in this query: `$nextItemQuery = "SELECT * FROM`items`WHERE size = 0  LIMIT :val1 ,1";` in http request from android/java? 
When I have to update rows in the table, I do this :

```
$nextItemQuery = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE picked = :picked  LIMIT 2,1";
$query_params = array(

    ':picked' => $_POST['picked']
);

 try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($nextItemQuery);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
```

and in the app I add variable to Hashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_PICKED, itPicked);
```

But since `LIMIT 2,1` is not a colum in the table I don't know how to access it and would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: The overall schema seems kinda..bad from first look, when you need to use LIMIT to pick a specific row you know something is wrong. I am almost at the point saying the whole concept is wrong.

do you want to update all the rows with picked = :picked ? then why query them 1 by 1? does query in batch doesn't work? if yes, why? Also how does your table look like, is there any primary key or value we could use? Also, show your update SQL if possible, maybe you could combine them together.

Comment: Thanks for reply @JackyCheng. The purpose of `LIMIT 2,1` is to update 1 row at a time (because I need one row at a time) and proceed to the next row. I would use rowID with auto_increment, but since it leaves gaps after deletion it wont work. However I agree with your point and after re-thinking, I decided to create rowId column and increment it manually. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: right, as a final note, even somehow you can only modify 1 row at a time, doesn't mean that you can't query for 50 rows in one go, save them all in a array/map, then use a for loop to "get from map, modify, update". That cuts "50 query, 50 updates" into "1 query, 50 update".